# On click take data-id find marching parent id and display none

Tags: jquery

When i click on a button with a data-id im trying to find the container with the matching ID and display none.

This is my HTML

```
<ul class="optionalExtrasBasket list-unstyled col-xs-12">
    @foreach (var OEModel in Model.OptionalExtras)
    {
        foreach (var x in OEModel.ProductExtras)
        {
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 border-bottom optional-extra-row">
                <div class="optional-extra-thankyou text-center">
                    <div class="loaderBox"></div>
                    <div class="">@x.Title</div>
                    <b>Has been added to your basket</b>
                </div>
                <div id="@x.ProductID" class="optional-extra-container">
                    <div class="optionalExtrasImage float-left margin-right">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="img-responsive" src="@(@WebLocation.GetImageMedium(x.PrimaryImageUrl))" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="optionalExtrasDetails float-right">
                        <div class="title">@x.Title</div>
                        <div class="price margin-top-half">@x.SalePrice.ToActiveCurrency()</div>
                        <div class="stock-avail">@x.StockAvailabilityState</div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;" class="margin-top">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" class="directProduct" id="directProduct" name="directProduct" value="@x.ProductID" />
                            <label for="product" class="visible-xs">Button</label>
                            <button style="width: 100%;" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block js-buynow" data-href="/ajax/AddToBasket?p=@x.ProductID" value="Add to Basket" data-text="Add to Basket" data-productid="@x.ProductID" title="Add to basket" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">Add to Basket</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    }
    <!-- END LI -->
</ul>
```

in the HTML above it button has a data-productid="@x.ProductID" and the parent container has a id="@x.ProductId"

any help or suggestions would be great

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you also checking if the container is hidden?

Comment: @Wolverine I'm not, I was just going to take your example and add on a display block for the thank you container. Your JS works fine btw, thanks for the help

Comment: @Wolverine as the thank you container above doesn't have an ID - do you happen to know how I would display this when the button is clicked? or would this need a relevant ID?

Comment: You can do it like this:

`$('#' + $(this).data().productid).parent().find('.optional-extra-thankyou').show();`

Comment: It would be good if you have an ID like you generate for the button and the div container. By the way, is this razor syntax you're working with?

Comment: If you want to have an ID on the `thank-you` container, you can generate it like this:

`<div class="optional-extra-thankyou text-center" id="@("thank-you-" + x.ProductID)">`

Then, in jQuery, add this line inside the button event, `$('#thank-you-' + $(this).data().productid).show();`

Comment: @Wolverine I appreciate the help, this works great and yes it is

Comment: Glad it works. You can use either of those two solutions for your `thank-you` container.

Comment: But the second solution is more reliable than the first one since it doesn't depend on the HTML structure. As long as it knows the ID, it doesn't matter where the element appears in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button[data-productid]').on('click', function () {
    $('#' + $(this).data().productid).hide();
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
   var dataID = $(this).attr('data-productid');
   $('.optionalExtrasBasket').find(dataID).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable with some commentary on what it does and why.  Thanks.